# query rewrite not working properly on materialized view datasubset

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I'm currently experimenting with Oracle materialized views, but I'm facing a problem:

I created a materialized view (a data subset that only contains data for January 2020) from base table DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE and matching bitmapindex:

```
create materialized view DW.MV_TSL_4
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
as
SELECT  "Fact_Timesheet_Line".*
FROM
DW."DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE" "Fact_Timesheet_Line"
WHERE  
"Fact_Timesheet_Line".DDAT_WORK_SK between 20200101 and 20200131
;

CREATE BITMAP INDEX DW.IDX_BM_MV_TSL_4_DDAT_WORK_SK ON DW.MV_TSL_4 (DDAT_WORK_SK) NOLOGGING TABLESPACE DW_INDEX PCTFREE    10 INITRANS   2 MAXTRANS   255 STORAGE    ( INITIAL          64K NEXT             1M MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED MINEXTENTS       1 MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED PCTINCREASE      0 BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT ) NOPARALLEL;
```

When I run the following query with a filter on DDAT_WORK_SK, the query is being rewritten by the optimize to use the materialized view:

```
select sum(data) from DW.DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE where DDAT_WORK_SK between 20200101 and 20200131

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |          |     1 |     4 | 14490   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE               |          |     1 |     4 |            |          |
|   2 |   MAT_VIEW REWRITE ACCESS FULL| MV_TSL_4 |  1732K|  6769K| 14490   (1)| 00:00:02 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note
-----
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold
```

However, If I change the query so that the base table is joined with table DW_D_DATE on column DDAT_WORK_SK, the query is rewritten to get the data from the materialized view and also from the base table (with a UNION ALL):

```
select sum(data)
from DW.DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE , DW.DW_D_DATE
where DW_D_DATE.DDAT_SK = DW.DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE.DDAT_WORK_SK and 
DW_D_DATE.DDAT_SK between 20200101 and 20200131;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |                          |     1 |    13 | 14500   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                          |                          |     1 |    13 |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                                   |                          |     2 |    26 | 14500   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   3 |    UNION-ALL                             |                          |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     SORT AGGREGATE                       |                          |     1 |    16 |            |          |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                           |                          |   131K|  2052K| 14500   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | DW_PK_DDAT_SK            |     2 |    12 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |       MAT_VIEW REWRITE ACCESS FULL       | MV_TSL_4                 |  1732K|    16M| 14494   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   8 |     SORT AGGREGATE                       |                          |     1 |    10 |            |          |
|*  9 |      FILTER                              |                          |       |       |            |          |
|  10 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE       |  2361K|    22M|   134K  (1)| 00:00:11 |
|  11 |        BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS       |                          |       |       |            |          |
|* 12 |         BITMAP INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_BM_FTSL_DDAT_WORK_SK |       |       |            |          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("DW_D_DATE"."DDAT_SK"="MV_TSL_4"."DDAT_WORK_SK")
   6 - access("DW_D_DATE"."DDAT_SK">=20200101 AND "DW_D_DATE"."DDAT_SK"<=20200131)
   7 - filter("MV_TSL_4"."DDAT_WORK_SK">=20200101 AND "MV_TSL_4"."DDAT_WORK_SK"<=20200131)
   9 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)
  12 - access("DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE"."DDAT_WORK_SK">=20200101 AND 
              "DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE"."DDAT_WORK_SK"<=20200131)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=5)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold
   - this is an adaptive plan
```

I don't understand why the optimizer is still using the base table?

In the explain plan, I noticed line '9 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)'. After some googling this could be because of constraints that are not being validated.

I tried to validate the foreign key constraint DW_FK_DDAT_WORK_SK on DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE and create a few extra constraints on this column:

```
alter table DW.DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE modify constraint DW_FK_DDAT_WORK_SK validate; 
alter table DW.DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE  add constraint testconstr check (DDAT_WORK_SK is not null) validate;

alter table DW.MV_TSL_4  add constraint t1a_ck check (DDAT_WORK_SK is not null) validate;
alter table DW.MV_TSL_4  add constraint t1a_ck2 check (DDAT_WORK_SK between 20200101 and 20200131) validate;
```

But even with these constraints, the optimizer continues to rewrite the query using a UNION ALL between the materialized view and the base table.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Check out the DBMS_MVIEW package which has a couple fo EXPLAIN_... API's which will give you feedback on whether the database *could* opt to rewrite a query.  If it decides it is not safe to do so, then no matter how good it looks, it wont happen

Answer (score 0):

`9 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)` means that Oracle knows it can safely not execute this part.

You can use row source statistics to confirm which lines are executed in a plan (and how many times and how long they take).

```
alter session set statistics_level=all;
set serverout off
select sum(data)
from DW.DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE , DW.DW_D_DATE
where DW_D_DATE.DDAT_SK = DW.DW_F_TIMESHEETLINE.DDAT_WORK_SK and 
DW_D_DATE.DDAT_SK between 20200101 and 20200131;
select * from dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id=>null,format=>'typical allstats last');
```

(assuming the user you're running this as has the privileges to read plans, otherwise grab the sql_id of the execution and run the `dbms_xplan` part manually from a privileged session).

I imagine, Oracle has decided to expand this out as there is a foreign key which guarantees that the join is always successful - so if you were to use the base table, you don't need to do the join.

BTW it is a small red flag to have bitmap indexes on this base table, make sure you really need them as they do not make concurrency easy. Should also note that none of your shared queries would benefit from the bitmap index you created on the MView.